# How to pass parameters to Stored Procedure in Microsoft Flow

Tags: power-automate, ms-forms

This is my first time to use Microsoft Flow

it looks easy but I am stuck at the moment

I want to pass data from MS Forms to my Stored Procedure using MS Flow

I managed to get the response ID but that is not enough, 
I want the rest of the data in the MS Forms

as in the image below

`List of response notifications Response id` will send the ID of the response 
but 
`Current item` will send this data

```
{"webhookId":"f912d0db-1dd4-4c7e-b655-ae75d4bb3d7a","eventType":"ResponseAdded","resourceData":{"formId":"dVLH1V-fFkuoPzxppiOnlzixU_JOYMlMpqOmPhdZrLpUREV0OU5VFFNJVE5XUE0GS15DQVVWTlFaMC4u","responseId":3},"eventTime":"2018-12-10T01:13:15.4185181Z"}
```

my question is how to pass user entry in the MS Forms to the SP?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add an extra action to your flow, to get the details of each row.

[image: Screenshot of Flow example]